# Add markers styling is not showing up in plotlly chart

Tags: r, plotly, scatter-plot, markers

```
plot_ly(data = bData,  x = ~`Maturity Date`, y =  ~YVal,  type = 'scatter', mode='markers', 
              color = ~Crncy, colors = setNames(rainbow(nrow(bData)), bData$Crncy),
              marker = list( opacity = 0.7, size=15) ,
              text = ~paste(" Security: ", bData$Security, "<br>",
                            "Currency: ", bData$Crncy, "<br>",
                            "YTM: ", bData$YTM,"<br>",
                            "DM: ", bData$DM)) %>% 
        layout(title="Rel Val", xaxis = list(title="Maturity"), 
               yaxis = list(title="FRN: DM | Fixed: YAS ASW USD")) %>% 
        add_markers(symbol = ~factor(bData$Sym),color = I("black"), marker = list( opacity = 1, size=9))
```

Above code produces this plot which is okay but if I add marker style it does not change anything

```
    add_markers(symbol = ~factor(bData$Sym),symbols = c('circle-open','x-open','diamond-open'),color = I("black"), marker = list( opacity = 1, size=9))
```

[image]